# Truncated incorrect Integer value '.'

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to insert using inner join from another table but I'm having problem.

IMSI table from BROADBAND_ICCBS_GROUPLIST datatype is BIGINT while varchar on LTE_ATHOME_APN .

```
INSERT INTO LTE_ATHOME_APN(IMSI)
    SELECT s.IMSI
    FROM SPEEDTEST_D s 
    INNER JOIN BROADBAND_ICCBS_GROUPLIST b ON s.IMSI = b.IMSI
```

Error Output:

```
SQL Error (1292): Truncated incorrect INTEGER value '.'
```

What would be the solution for this?

Comment: Well, what do you want to do with that value?

Comment: I'm inserting the IMSI from table b to LTE_ATHOME_APN.

Comment: What is the datatype of `SPEEDTEST_D.IMSI` (as that is the one you are inserting, not `BROADBAND_ICCBS_GROUPLIST.IMSI`)?

Comment: The datatype is BIGINT

Comment: Are you sure? `'.'` Isnt an integer.

Comment: Why do these columns have inconsistent data types?

Comment: This were already set in the database. I'm just getting it and inserting to my table

Comment: `SELECT IMSI FROM LTE_ATHOME_APN WHERE IMSI LIKE '%.%';`  I think you will see the problem.   If not, we will explain it.

Comment: Hi @RickJames LTE_ATHOME_APN is where I want to insert the data. Basically it's blank

Comment: @Aleo - Oops, search the other table instead.

Answer (score 0):

well, it is probably an issue about column ordering.

use

```
insert into (<column_names>)
     select <column_names> from ..
```